# How to merge two tables having the same column in both the tables in order to identify the discrepancies in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am not very proficient in MySQL: My questions is I have two tables: t1 and t2

t1

```
Name, ID
```

t2

```
ID, types
```

I want to merge both t1 and t2 only columns containing the ID's and identify why I have the difference in these ID's.

Comment: At the very least post (add to your question by using [Edit]) some sample data and the desired output.  Based on your description, you might need `FULL OUTER JOIN` functionality that is not natively available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the mysql function **MERGE**

An other alternative would be to add the column types in t1 and update it to add missing data. I assume here your types type is VARCHAR(60):

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD [COLUMN] types VARCHAR(60);

UPDATE t1,t2 SET t1.types=t2.types WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID;

DROP TABLE t2;
```